# How to describe complex response objects at the client in graphql Apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo

I use graphql apollo at the server and client.
The server has a mutation that returns a very complex object which has nested relations, etc.
[image: the complex graphql mutation response type]

so how can it be described at the client?

I tried to describe explicitly each field like grapqhl requires, but it's very exhausting and ugly. Furthermore, the fields on the schema has linked relations and I don't know how to describe it in the graphql response.
I'm not sure if fragments can help me in this case.

```
export const CREATE_COMMUNITY_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation CreateCommunity($data: CreateCommunityInput!) {
    createCommunity(data: $data) {
      id,
      name,
      about,
      owner {
        id,
        email,
        bio,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        profileUrl,
        locale,
        username,
        account,
        timeBasedFeed,
        scoreBasedFeed,
      },
      color,
      pictureUrl,
      timeBasedFeed,
      scoreBasedFeed,
      topics {
        id,
        name,
        image,
        timeBasedFeed,
        storeBasedFeed,
        aliases,
        parents,
        allAncestors
      },
      members {
        edges {
          cursor,
          node {
            id,
            email,
            bio,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            profileUrl,
            locale,
            username,
            account,
            timeBasedFeed,
            scoreBasedFeed,
          }
        },
        totalCount,
        pageInfo {
            startCursor
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            count
          },
      }
      blockedUsers {
        edges {
          cursor,
          node {
            id,
            email,
            bio,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            profileUrl,
            locale,
            username,
            account,
            timeBasedFeed,
            scoreBasedFeed,
          }
        },
        totalCount,
        pageInfo {
            startCursor
            endCursor
            hasNextPage
            hasPreviousPage
            count
          },
      },
      admins {
        users {
          id,
            email,
            bio,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            profileUrl,
            locale,
            username,
            account,
            timeBasedFeed,
            scoreBasedFeed,
        }
      },
      moderators {
        users {
          id,
            email,
            bio,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            profileUrl,
            locale,
            username,
            account,
            timeBasedFeed,
            scoreBasedFeed,
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Maybe someone could give some suggestion/idea how to handle it?
thanks for any help

Comment: it's simple ... overfetching. .. abusing graphql .... usually you need  one or a few fields as mutation result ... any other data [with related childs] can be read on demand, at components, consuming only those data chunks .... simply no need to read more data than required for current task/view..... you can but you shouldn't

Comment: Hi @xadm. Thanks for your suggestion. It's really useful for me because I'm new in graphql world thus it looks like I'm trying to apply REST patterns where an endpoint returns everything. 
I tried to omit the nested fields describing but the apollo client threw an error: **"Field "account" of type "Account!" must have a selection of subfields.**  . That's why I thought I need to describe all nested fields for all relations.

Comment: play with `/graphiql` (sandbox) before coding ... you should not query for a parent node (type with props/fields) without asking for childs [if any exist] ... **no `account` alone, only with any number of childs**